# how to get current input field index by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input, html-table

I have following html table layout:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td>Some cell text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    <td>Some cell text</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Some cell text</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to know the current input field index of respective row while click on any input field but can't figure out a way to get it. I can get total number of input fields (length) of each row by following formula:

```
var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
var inputLength = thisRow.find('input[type="text"]').length;
```

As for example the `inputLength` for first row is `4` and second row is `3`. But how can I get the input index when a user clicks on 2nd input field of first row (it should be 1)?

[note: I can't use `td` index as alternative of `input` field index as you may see that there might have been some `td` which have no `input` field. As a result, if I run a `for loop` it can't be performed as I expected.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method as follows:

```js
$(':input').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('tr').find(':input').index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>Some cell text</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>Some cell text</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Some cell text</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also see [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: I don't know whether there is more suitable solution or not, but till now, this is the only solution I got from you. If no other user can give more suitable solution within today, I will accept your answer.

Comment: It works as well with element that contains `data-*` like `$('[data-nav]').focus(function() {$(this).closest('tr').find('[data-nav]:input').index($(this))})`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery index but not on the `input` itself but on the `td` parent.

```
var thisRow = $(this).parent('td');
var id = $('td').index(thisRow);
```

The id above would be the index of `td` and therefor the index of input.

Comment: I can't use `td` index as alternative of `input` index. There may be some `td` in the middle of the same row which have no input fields. So, if a row has 10 `tds` and 8 `input` fields, then obviously index of td will not match index of input field.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid You did not mention that situation in your question as all td element in the code you provided in the question actually has an input.

Answer (score 1):

please check the below solution

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keypress', function(e){
    $this = $(this);   

    var td = $this.parents('td');
    var tr = $this.parents('tr');

    var col = td.parent().children().index(td);

    $('div').html('you are changing the value of column.#. '+col)

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93k7g4v7/

Comment: I can't use td index as alternative of input index. There may be some td in the middle of the same row which have no input fields. So, if a row has 10 tds and 8 input fields, then obviously index of td will not match index of input field. I have updated your fiddle with one td which has no `input` field. Now look at the index differences. link: https://jsfiddle.net/93k7g4v7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) . Example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var listItem = document.getElementById("bar");
alert("Index: " + $("li").index(listItem));
```

Comment: List item and table row are two different things. Here you all have list items (li) in a user list (ul). But in a table row there may be less number of input fields than td/cell numbers. So the identifying of index will be different in those two cases.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function(){
        var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index('tr');
        if (rowIndex == 0) {
            var inputIndex = $('tr:eq(0) input[type="text"]').index(this);
        } 
        else if (rowIndex == 1) {
            var inputIndex = $('tr:eq(1) input[type="text"]').index(this);
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mjollnir40/es7o8jf5/6/

Comment: Sorry, but your fiddle is empty (blank)!! If I check your fiddle in a suitable fiddle, I found your code gives cumulative index of all input fields. As for example, if row-01 have 5 input fields (with one blank td), it gives index of last input field as 3, it is okay. But from second row, index of first input begins from 4, it should not be. It should be from 0 again.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the changes. It'll work for you now. You just alert `inputIndex` or set it equal to a var or whatever you need.

Comment: Sorry, but your updated fiddle does not alert or show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.each(function(index, element){})` to attach `click` event handler , reference `index` of `input` element at `click` handler

```js
$("input").each(function(index) {
  this.onclick = function() {
    console.log(index)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td>Some cell text</td><td></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td>Some cell text</td><td></td><td>Some cell text</td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```